# Issue in Pagination in jQuery jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

In the jQuery-jqGrid code below, pagination is not working. I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jq-grid-1000000</title>
</head>
<body>        
    <style type="text/css">

        /* set the size of the datepicker search control for Order Date*/
        #ui-datepicker-div { font-size:11px; }
        .ui-datepicker { z-index: 2000 }

        /* set the size of the autocomplete search control*/
        .ui-menu-item {
            font-size: 11px;
        }

         .ui-autocomplete {
            z-index: 2000;
            font-size: 11px;
        }       

    </style>

    <table id="jqGrid"></table>
    <div id="jqGridPager"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/getjsonp.php?callback=?&qwery=longorders',
                mtype: "GET",
                datatype: "jsonp",
                page: 1,
                colModel: [
                    {   label : "Order ID",                     
                        name: 'OrderID', 
                        key: true, 
                        width: 75 
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Customer ID",
                        name: 'CustomerID',
                        width: 150
                    },
                    { 
                        label: "Order Date",
                        name: 'OrderDate',
                        width: 150,                     
                        sorttype:'date'                        
                    },                    
                    {
                        label : "Ship Name",
                        name: 'ShipName',
                        width: 150
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Freight",
                        sorttype: 'number',
                        name: 'Freight', 
                        width: 150
                    }
                ],
                loadonce: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                width: 780,
                height: "auto",
                page: 1,
                rowNum: 3,
                pager: "#jqGridPager",
                gridview: true, 
                autoencode: true
            });
            // activate the build in search with multiple option            
              $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('navGrid',"#jqGridPager", {           
                search: true, // show search button on the toolbar
                add: false,
                edit: false,
                del: false,
                refresh: true               
            },
            {}, // edit options
            {}, // add options
            {}, // delete options
            { 
                multipleSearch: true, 
                multipleGroup : true,               
            }
            );
        });

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: I see you use free-jqGrid, but your code is get from Guriddo jqGrid. Not sure if this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The paging will not work, because you use the option loadonce: true. With this option after the first request the datatype is going local with 3 records and you do not have more rows to page.

Disable this option and your paging will work.